# Set value and echo "input field"

Tags: php, echo

I want to set value **(value="Self_Study")** to this input field,
I echo this input field as follows

```
echo '<div class="col-md-4 pull-left hidden self" id="self">
 <input id="' . $SubjectID . '" name="textinput" type="text"  class="input-md tution_provider" placeholder="Self Study" value="Self_Study" disabled>
</div>'
```

But that value is not echo
[image]

how to echo that value ?

Comment: If you paste your code in snippet its working fine.

Comment: I highly recommend using PHP only for the PHP parts in your HTML and using `htmlspecialchars` for proper encoding, eg `<input id="<?= htmlspecialchars($SubjectID) ?>"...`

Comment: When I using your code then it is working fine for me. But there may be some html characters for subjectID then you have to use the method for it

Comment: @PHPGeek this is part of my code this code is in the for loop

Comment: @RJParikh PHPGeek this is part of my code this code is in the for loop

Comment: add those loop also..there is no error that what you have posted@samrulz ss

Comment: thanks @phi it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Using **htmlspecialchars()** It nicely worked

```
echo  '<div class="col-md-4 pull-left hidden self" id="self">
    <input id="' . $SubjectID . '" name="textinput" type="text"  class="input-md tution_provider"  value="' . htmlspecialchars('Self Study') . '" disabled>
    </div>'
```

Comment: This makes no sense at all

Answer (score 0):

try it..

`echo '<div class="col-md-4 pull-left hidden self" id="self">
 <input id="<?php echo $SubjectID; ?>" name="textinput" type="text"  class="input-md tution_provider" placeholder="Self Study" value="<?php echo $variable; ?>" disabled>
</div>'`